# How to find number of images in active excel cell using office js

Tags: office-js

Actually, I'm new to Office Js.

In excel office add-in I have placed multiple images in particular cell. If the user save the sheet and opens again, I need to find out how many images are placed in that cell.

[image: Pls find the image]

How to find that the cell contains how many images?

I'm expecting image count for particular active excel cell.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature: Getting image count for a particular active cell, you mentioned, seems not a part of Excel JS API. Microsoft Office JS Team tracks Office Add-in feature requests on [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Maybe you could add your request there. Thanks!